# Twig internationalization not showing results

Tags: php, internationalization, twig

Search on several forums but cannot find what is wrong with my code.
I have built a custom MVC framework and implemented Twig:

The View class has a function to fetch a template which includes:

```
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\I18nExtension());
```

The index.php file includes:

```
// Set language to English
putenv('LC_All=en_GB');
//putenv("LANGUAGE=en_GB");
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');
// Specify the location of the translation tables
bindtextdomain('mydomain', './locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset('mydomain', 'UTF-8');
// Choose domain
textdomain('mydomain');
```

I have created .po and .mo files and placed them both in:
locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES

A page includes twig tags:

```
<div class="header">
    <h2>{% trans 'Log in' %}</h2>
</div>
```

No translation nor the original are showing up.
No errors are shown.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Not really good with twig translations but your formatting seems incorrect, check https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#trans

Comment: I guess I am using old version. I just found this from another post, so I need to look further. At least with the adjusted format I get the original text: 

Translation are not working in twig with the tag {% trans %} or with the filter |trans because you are not using the default translator service of Symfony but one you just instantiate.

Comment: Still twig does not seem to be able to find the files and load them

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using new code (replacing some of the standard i18n files) posted recently on Github. This code enables Twig templates to use `|trans` and `{% trans %}` + `{% endtrans %}` again.

[Github - Twig-trans](https://github.com/JBlond/twig-trans)